# How to use mouselockAPI?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have Firefox nightly, Opera next, and Google Chrome, but I can't test the mouselock API on them (why?). I downloaded a special version of FF nightly, which should support it, but it also doesn't support.

May be an error with my computer?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, maybe show some code and the exact version numbers.

Comment: the demos in here: http://humphd.github.com/mozilla-central/mouselock/

Comment: sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/API/Pointer_Lock_API

The Pointerlock isn't supported in any browser.